# Ontotext GraphDB SPARQL Query - No acceptable file format found

Tags: sparql, graphdb

Ontotext GraphDB 9.0.0, Free Edition, Ubuntu Workstation Linux 4.15.0-65-generic x86_64

I have a simple SPARQL query that works fine in the Query & Update page and from the web service:

```
select * where { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
} limit 5
```

and if I don't provide an *Accept:* header I get the results back as comma separated values.  However, if I provide a file format like this:

```
$ curl -G -H "Accept: text/turtle" 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/...'
No acceptable file format found.
```

Is there list of or a REST query for acceptable media types?

Comment: everything is in the docs of RDF4J: https://rdf4j.eclipse.org/documentation/rest-api/#_content_types

Comment: For the SPARQl results formats, see the list of specs at the start of the query spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SELECT query does not return an RDF graph (in Turtle or any other synatx)- it returns a SPARQL Result set.

`application/sparql-results+json` is one format.

If you want an RDF graph, use a CONSTRUCT query and you can ask for text/turtle:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 5
```

That particular query can be shortened to:

```
CONSTRUCT WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 5
```